# How to access request headers only in a rails 2 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails provides a request.headers method that returns both all headers and a lot of extra non-header information... i would like to access only the request headers, how can I do so?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You essentially have to isolate all **environment entries** which are prefixed with `HTTP_` or `CONTENT_`, which correspond to your HTTP headers, e.g:

```
# CONTENT_LENGTH -> Content-Length
# HTTP_COOKIE -> Cookie
# HTTP_USER_AGENT -> User-Agent
@headers |= request.env.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)|
  if k =~ /^(HTTP|CONTENT)_/ then
    h[k.sub(/^HTTP_/, '').dasherize.gsub(/([^\-]+)/) { $1.capitalize }] = v 
  end
  h
}
```

Alternatively, you can be more restrictive and only look for **specific** [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) in order to avoid accidentally picking up environment variables that may look like headers but are not actually valid such as `CONTENT_BLA` or `HTTP_DUMMY`.

```
@headers |= %w[ CONTENT_LENGTH CONTENT_TYPE HTTP_ACCEPT
HTTP_REFERER HTTP_USER_AGENT ].inject({}) { |h, k|
  if v = request.env[k] then
    h[k.sub(/^HTTP_/, '').dasherize.gsub(/([^\-]+)/) { $1.capitalize }] = v 
  end
  h
}
```

Take a look at `actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb` to see how they comb the environment to extract request headers.

Comment: I can't actually go for the second one because all http headers (i.e. extended headers) are unknown to the server. Those headers, as X-Runtime, will appear as env HTTP_X-RUNTIME?

Regards

Comment: That would be `HTTP_X_RUNTIME` in the environment, and `X-Runtime` in the resulting `@headers` hash.  The second snippet only uses a "white list" of headers that could be interesting to you (to filter out uninteresting stuff); if something on the whitelist isn't actually present in your environment, it does not get added to `@headers`; also the other way around, if it's in the environment but not on the whitelist it does not get added to `@headers`.

Comment: Thanks Vlad... ill go with the first option: I need all request headers - even those I am unaware of, so I cant go with a white list.

Comment: isn't there any way that request object provide the http headers only instead of parsing them ourselves ?